# Concatenating Numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript

My goal is to make numbers into strings.

If my actual = concatenateNumbers(7);
expected = "7"
My code for this would be:

```
function concatenateNumbers(num1) {
    return num1.toString();
}
```

However, if my actual has 2 or 3 more values, actual = concatenateNumbers(7, 9) or actual = (7, 9 ,1) => the expected is = "79" or "791"

Can anybody give me an idea or hint on how I should approach this?

Comment: `return` can pass only a single value. What kind of return value type you want? An array? An object? Something else?

Comment: `function concatenateNumbers(...nums) { return nums.join(''); }`

Comment: @ChrisG `concatenateNumbers = "".concat.bind("")`

Comment: js will automatically stringify that for you, you don't need explicit conversion, where are your other numbers for the argument?

Comment: I'm still fairly new to javscript, i haven't dealt with arrays or object.

Comment: use @Chris G s answer then

Comment: How do I contest "Duplicate"? -> this is NOT a duplicate as it has nothing to do with Arrays (specifically) AND it is requesting a function (implied) and the supposed duplicated is not (necessarily) a solution as a function.

Answer (score 0):

Use [The arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) converted to a real Array, and use [Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) with an empty String:

```js
function concatenateNumbers() {
  return [...arguments].join("");
}

var numbersArrays = [
  [],
  [7],
  [7, 9],
  [7, 9, 1]
];

numbersArrays.forEach(numbersArray=>{
  console.log(numbersArray.join(", ") + " => " + concatenateNumbers(...numbersArray));
});

console.log("1, 2, 3 => "+concatenateNumbers(1, 2, 3));
```

`numbersArrays` is just a convenient way to use SO's code snippet, along with `"["+numbersArray.join(", ")+"]"` to show each `numbersArrays`'s Array as an Array, plus the actual call to the actual function `concatenateNumbers`.

**Edited** to make function's arguments actually a list of Numbers using the [Spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), as pointed out by [VLAZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3689450/vlaz).

It will actually concatenate anything, the best it can...

Comment: You're passing arrays when calling the function instead of just numbers. The log should probably be `numbersArray.join(", ")  + " => "+concatenateNumbers(...numbersArray))`

Comment: @VLAZ, you are correct, I've up-voted your comment, and adjusted the answer.

Comment: Just in general, I personally try to present my examples [something like this](https://jsbin.com/qejelolihe/edit?js,console). Yes, the code is repetitive, but I think it's clearer to see what happens.